# c++ iterators, alternative syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax, iterator, language-design

For some object V that is iterable, iterating on it commonly uses this syntax (here with std::transform)

```
std::transform(V.begin(), V.end(), V.begin(), /*somelamda*/ );
```

Here V is specified 3 times. One would think that an overloaded (albeit less flexible) function could exist for the common use-case.

```
std::transform(V, /*somelamda*/ );
```

When `V` is a `VeryLongNameLikeThis` the first syntax becomes difficult to write, to read and even prone to error when you have variables with similar `VeryLongNameLikeThis2`.

Question: What other syntaxes are available for iteration in *special* but *common* use-cases like the above (eg. where there is only one object `V` involved and `.begin()` comes before `.end()` and so on)? In case the designers opted to not offer "shorthands" what could their motivations be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verbosity of the `.begin()`-`.end()` pattern is a well-known (minor) issue. C++20 will mitigate this:

```
#include <ranges>

std::ranges::transform(V, dest.begin(), /* some function */);
```

But note that the second argument is mandatory (as opposed to your snippet), because a destination of the result of the transformation will always be needed. Prior to C++20, you can use a range library, e.g. [Boost range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) or [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

For the second part of your question, the most remarkable ease of iterating ranges is the range based for loop:

```
for (const auto& element : V)
   /* do stuff */;
```

which is especiall elegant when iterating over a (flat) map, as it can be combined with structured bindings:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : someMap)
   /* do stuff */;
```

These constructs use the function templates `std::begin` and `std::end` under the hood (which dispatch to the corresponding member functions for e.g. containers).